# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] while trying to make a call using asterisk

Tags: python-3.x, asterisk

I am trying to [initiate a call](https://www.banquise.org/python/how-to-dial-a-number-using-asterisk-and-python/) using asterisk.

```
HOST = "182.156.197.37"
PORT = 5060
# indian number 89788xxxxx country code 91
click_to_call(phone_to_dial='0119189788xxxxx',
              username = 'xxxxx', password = "xxxxxx",
              local_user = '600')
```

I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Trails/testcall.py", line 45, in <module>
local_user = '600')
  File "D:/Projects/Trails/testcall.py", line 30, in click_to_call
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I dont have any extension numbers, so I tried like

```
click_to_call(phone_to_dial='011918978833992',
              username = 'xxxxx', password = "xxxxxx",
              local_user = '')
```

but still I have the same error. How to rectify the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check firewall, check /etc/asterisk/manager.conf and included files for bind ip.

Comment: how do we include bind IP files? I just pip installed asterisk and registered with the asterisk. just modified the details with mine in the link. I have no information regarding the local_user. what is meant by local_user here ?

Comment: my firewall allows, no issues with it.

Comment: Read file i refer above.